# How to add an attribute to another model without modifying its table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Apologies for the word salad in the title, I'm very new to Rails dev. I have two models:

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to: project
  ...
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: templates
  ...
end
```

I also have the fact that each `Template` has multiple `Project`. (I think I need to add this somewhere?). I wish to add a `selected` attribute to the each `Project` but I can not modify the `Project` table (for reasons). Therefore, I need to add this attribute on the `Template` model side and I was wondering how should I do this?

Comment: The relationship of these models should be many-to-many?

Comment: If you can add a table go with has `many through`

Comment: This is the case of many-to-many. You mentioned that you cannot change `Project` table, but can you tell if you can create another new table?

Comment: @allenbrkn Yes, I'm able to.